# .on() not working for generated elements

Tags: jquery

AFAICT this should work but it doesn't. Using jQuery 1.9.0, I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("#area").html("<p>click me</p>");
                });

                $("p").on("click", function() {
                    alert($(this).text());
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>some text</p>
        <button>Create me</button>
        <div id="area"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does clicking on "some text" bring the alert but clicking on the generated "click me" not? I thought the whole point of .on() was to enable event handlers on dynamically generated code. According to [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) this should work but it doesn't. See http://jsfiddle.net/ymUYy/1/

Comment: [Please read the jQuery `.on()` documentation where delegation is clearly explained.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Please don't frame the question in as "generated elements" because it is part of the confusion that makes people misunderstand how event delegation works. The `.on()` docs describe it pretty clearly I think. The element where you attach the event _must_ exist at the time you attach the event. The idea is that events from elements that are _below_ that may occur later, and those elements may not yet exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.on()` isn't a drop-in replacement for `.live()`. You need to use the event delegation syntax:

```
$('#area').on('click', 'p', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: The important thing to know about delegation is that the elements you apply `.on()` to must exist at the time you call it, the elements named in the 2nd argument can be added dynamically.